# lsusb: can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: lsusb, mx-linux

I'm unable to get `Report Descriptors` for my usb device using `lsusb -v`.
I'm running it as root but I'm still only getting:

```
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
```

My USB devices seem to work but every most usb entries give out errors like:

```
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**outputs of `lsusb -vd <vid>:<pid>`:**

```
root@mx:/home/bobajeff# lsusb -vd 046d:c069

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct          0xc069 M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
  bcdDevice           56.01
  iManufacturer           1 Logitech
  iProduct                2 USB Laser Mouse
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 U56.01_B0009
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower               98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      71
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0006  1x 6 bytes
        bInterval              10
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
root@mx:/home/bobajeff# lsusb -vd 056a:00b1

Bus 002 Device 006: ID 056a:00b1 Wacom Co., Ltd PTZ-630 [Intuos3 (6x8)]
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x056a Wacom Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x00b1 PTZ-630 [Intuos3 (6x8)]
  bcdDevice            1.02
  iManufacturer           1 Tablet
  iProduct                2 PTZ-630
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0022
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              300mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.00
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     170
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               4
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

root@mx:/home/bobajeff# lsusb -vd 1d6b:0003

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            5.08
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 5.8.0-3-amd64 xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 5: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
   Port 6: 0000.02a0 5Gbps power Rx.Detect
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x000f
  bNumDeviceCaps          1
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   3
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         512 micro seconds
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Why is my system unable to get `device qualifier`, `debug descriptor` or `Report Descriptors` from my usb devices? Can this be fixed?

Comment: From your tags, we see you run MX-Linux. On what hardware ? Are you quite certain the linked page you mentioned dealing with plain vanilla ubuntu applies to you?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator I've removed mention of the tutorial and clarified the issue to avoid further confusion.